# jQuery Datepicker not working after $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have looked through dozens of similar questions, but none of the answers given have worked.  I am calling an HTML form via $.post, and there is a datepicker field in this form.  I have been reading as much as I can about .live (deprecated) and .on to attempt to make the returned form live in the DOM - but have not been able to get it working properly.

This is how I am calling the form now:

```
$(".projectListHead").on('click', function() {
    var thisId = '12';  
    $.post('/admin/ajax/projects/manage.php', { id: thisId }, function(data) {
        $("#addEditArea").html(data) 
    });
});
```

I also tried:

```
$("body").on('click', ".projectListHead", function() {
        var thisId = '12';
            $.post('/admin/ajax/projects/manage.php', { id: thisId }, function(data) {
                $("#addEditArea").html(data);
                $(".datepicker").datepicker();
            });
    });
```

This also did not work.

This is the `datepicker` input field in the form returned in 'data':

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datePickThis" />
```

And the script selecting the `datepicker` field:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();
```

** UPDATE **

I tried a suggestion that made perfect sense, and worked in JSFiddle, but would not work:

```
$(".projectListHead").click(function() {
        var thisId = '12';
        $.post('/admin/ajax/projects/manage.php', { id: thisId }, function(data) {
                $("#addEditArea")
                .html(data)
                .find('.datepicker')
                .datepicker();
            });
    });
```

but this example works if I simply override the .html value like this:

```
$(".projectListHead").click(function() {
        var thisId = '12';
        $.post('/admin/ajax/projects/manage.php', { id: thisId }, function(data) {
                $("#addEditArea")
                .html('<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datePickThis" />')
                .find('.datepicker')
                .datepicker();
            });
    });
```

Also, I know it's long but here is the entirety of the HTML I am calling back.  Maybe the problem lies here:

```
<!-- PROJECT INFORMATION HEADER --------->
    <div class="projManHeader">
        <div class="clientPhoto" style="background-image: url(/admin/customers/images/4_thumb.jpg);"></div>
        <div class="projectInfo">
            <h1>William Richards</h1>
            <h2>Family Portraits</h2>
            <span style="font-size: 13px;">at Davis Arboretum</span>
        </div>
            <div class="projectDateInfo">
            <h1>July 19th</h1>
            <h2>6:30 PM</h2>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- NAVIGATION ICON MENU ------>
        <!-- PRELOAD IMAGE DIV ---->
        <div style="display: none">
            <img src="/images/icons/megaphone_over.gif" />
            <img src="/images/icons/infocircle_over.gif" />
            <img src="/images/icons/staffcircle_over.gif" />
            <img src="/images/icons/paycircle_over.gif" />
        </div>
    <div class="projectIconsContainer">
        <div id="comIcon" class="comIcon"></div>
        <div class="sectionHeader">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Contact</span><br />
            <span style="font-size: 9px;">Email Sent<br />
            on Aug 31, 2013
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="infoCircleIcon"></div>
        <div class="sectionHeader">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Project Info</span><br />
            <span style="font-size: 9px;">Email Sent<br />
            on Aug 31, 2013
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="staffCircleIcon"></div>
        <div class="sectionHeader">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Staff</span><br />
            <span style="font-size: 9px;">Shooter:<br />
            Leah Parker
            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="payCircleIcon"></div>
        <div class="sectionHeader">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">Payments</span><br />
            <span style="font-size: 9px;">Cost:<br />
            $160.00
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END NAVIGATION ICON MENU -->

    <!-- BEGIN AJAX FILL AREA ------>

    <div id="ajaxFillArea"></div>



    <!---- END AJAX FILL AREA ----->


    <!-- BEGIN HIDDEN COMMUNICATION DIV ----->

    <div id="hiddenComDiv" style="display:none;">
        <div style="padding: 15px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">
            <h2>Communication</h2>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; float: right; vertical-align: middle; margin-top: 13px; margin-right: 30px;">
            <input type="button" id="newComButton" value="NEW COMMUNICATION" />
        </div><br />
        <div id="newComForm" style="display: none;">
            <div style="padding: 15px; width: 600px; min-height: 300px; background-color: #f0f0f0; border: solid 1px #ccc;">
            <div style="padding: 5px; width: 100px; display: inline-block; text-align: right;">Send Email:</div>
            <div style="padding: 5px; display:inline-block;">
                <input type="text" name="comEmailSubject" style="width: 430px;" placeholder="email subject here" />
            </div><br />
            <div style="padding: 5px; width: 100px; display: inline-block; text-align: right;">Message:</div>
            <div style="padding: 5px; display:inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                <textarea name="comEmailMessage" style="width: 430px; height: 110px;" placeholder="email message here" ></textarea>
            </div><br />

            <div style="padding: 5px; width: 100px; display: inline-block; text-align: right;">Notes:</div>
            <div style="padding: 5px; display:inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
                <textarea name="comEmailNotes" style="width: 430px; height: 50px;" placeholder="followup / notes go here" ></textarea>
            </div><br />

            <div style="padding: 5px; width: 100px; display: inline-block; text-align: right;"></div>

            <div style="padding: 5px; display:inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
            <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="datePickThis" />
            <input type="button" value="SEND" />
            <input type="button" value="CANCEL" />  
            </div><br />

            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- HIDDEN COMMUNICATION DIV JQUERY -------->

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // NEW COMMUNICATION FORM
        $("#newComButton").click(function() {
            $("#newComForm").slideDown(function() {
                $("input[name=comEmailSubject]").focus();   
            });

        });

        // OPEN COMMUNICATION SECTION

        $("#comIcon").click(function() {
            var hiddenHtml = $("#hiddenComDiv").html();
            $("#ajaxFillArea").html(hiddenHtml);
        });

    });
    </script>

    </div>
```

The form returned in 'data' displays properly, but the `datepicker` simply won't work.  `Datepicker` does work perfectly when not called through ajax.  After three hours of digging, I'm hoping someone can clue me in here.  Thanks so much!

Comment: `var thisId = $(this).attr('projectid');`  ???

Comment: Can you please post data which is return after ajax.

Comment: I simplified the code that may have been confusing, and added part of the form that is returned.  It is a large form, so I didn't want to post the entire thing - I can if that helps.

Comment: You're not overwriting any of the form content are you? What is #addEditArea in relation to the form?

Comment: Did you try to put '$(".datepicker").datepicker();' after  $("#addEditArea").html(data) , inside de $.post ?

Comment: #addEditArea is simply an empty DIV in the current page that the data will be placed in.  I tried putting $(".datepicker").datepicker(); into the $.post with no success.  I also tried changing my selector to: $("body").on('click', ".projectListHead", function() - also with no success.

Comment: Did you try .livequery? You need this library: https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery . I used it like this: $(".datepicker").livequery(function(){ 
 $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
});

Comment: Created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BACse/), it seems to work. Can you replicate the issue and post it here?

Comment: Logically that example ins JSFiddle is exactly what I'm trying to do.  But it's still not working?  I am now including both an example of how I tried to implement this method, and the entirety of the HTML I am calling back.  Maybe there is something wrong inside the HTML I am bringing back that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I created something similar a while ago. Though it's function to add a input field, the idea is about the same.

```
$("#addDate").click(function() {
    var newDate = '<input type="text" class="dateSelector" value="" />';
    $(newDate).insertBefore('#dateBeforeThis');
    $( ".dateSelector" ).datepicker();
});
```

I don't know does it matter how you place the code on the page, whether using .html() or .insertBefore(), but this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I did the following after the content loads, to resolve the issue:

```
$("#datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker');
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
             changeMonth: true, 
             changeYear: true
});
```